# Is it possible to record DirecTV box or Xbox 360 through HDMI-IN on a PC?

Tags: hdmi, recording

I was wondering this after I found out that my Alienware Alpha had this HDMI-IN port. (the only reason why I bought the Alpha was because it was on sale for $399)

I did some research but could not find a clear answer regarding if this is possible or not. Thanks.

Comment: You need additional hardware to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The Alienware Alpha is intended to be used as a PC/Console connected to a large screen TV and that port is almost certainly a dumb "pass through" port and has no video capture hardware inside.

This means that you are likely to use it alongside DVD, bluray, satellite receivers and similar, all of which need a HDMI port on your TV. This would be "yet another" device that needs to use one of those HDMI port so rather than blocking that port and making you have to swap one device for another you can instead put it in-line with another device. If you have enough ports on your TV now then you will still have enough ports to plug in all your devices.

Unless the product blurb specifically mentions "you can capture your console gaming" then I would assume this is simply a dumb port pass through. A HDMI capture card would probably increase the cost of an already low cost device by too large an amount for too little benefit.